Unable to extract chart data dexscreener
I am trying to get chart data in OHLC format, but this data is not visible in the page source or the network tab.
Here is example url https://dexscreener.com/solana/ekmeoxul1ef44gn1yfpsfjb21ulbblzrdjwvcc7vtbed
I am expecting to take that chart data and convert it into Open, Close, High, and Low values. I know how to perform the conversion, but the data is not visible, and I cannot see any activity in the console or network tab. How is the chart updating? I will appreciate your help.

Have you addressed the Cloudflare challenge? I got it immediately on first opening the link.

Nope, you can use stored profile with selenium and open the link.
